# Spivak Calculus on Manifolds Theorem 5.1 and Theorem 2.13

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds

Theorem 5.1 (page 111) states that if $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is open, $g \colon A \to \mathbb{R}^p$ is a (continuously) differentiable map such that $g'(x)$ has rank $p$ whenever $g(x) = 0$, then
$g^{-1}(0)$ is a $(n-p)$-dimensional manifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Shouldn't that be a $p$-dimensional manifold?

Also, the proof of Theorem 2.13 is a bit baffling to me – how does the previous proof of the Implicit Function Theorem given (in Theorem 2.12) imply that there is a function “$h$ such that $f \circ h(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = (x_{n-p+1}, \ldots, x_n)$”?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please don't include unrelated questions in the same question. Multiples make it harder to compare answers and might discourage someone who can answer one of them from posting.

Comment: Duh. its $g$ INVERSE. i kept seeing $g$ - and the Rank Theorem was in my head. Thanks for pointing it out. Funny how these blind spots are hard to overcome.